# sed does nothing on hexa

Tags: linux, sed, hex

I want to replace a newline byte on a single-byte file with a sed

```
-(mar. déc. 05 11:45:16)--(moddgsa001.a2297:/home/marc/avirer)-
[root] # ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1  5 déc.  11:45 saut-de-ligne_UTF-8
-(mar. déc. 05 11:53:52)--(moddgsa001.a2297:/home/marc/avirer)-
[root] # od -h saut-de-ligne_UTF-8
0000000 000a
0000001
-(mar. déc. 05 11:53:57)--(moddgsa001.a2297:/home/marc/avirer)-
[root] #  sed -i 's/\x0a/\x25/g' saut-de-ligne_UTF-8
-(mar. déc. 05 11:54:06)--(moddgsa001.a2297:/home/marc/avirer)-
[root] # od -h saut-de-ligne_UTF-8
0000000 000a
0000001
```

But this does nothing. I don't understand. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed works on lines that end in `\x0a`, the character is not part of the string it acts on.

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -i -pe 's/\x0a/\x25/' saut-de-ligne_UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

The line separator is not part of the text that `sed` operates on. Hence, you cannot replace it.

You can use `tr` to do the translation:

```
tr '\012' '\045' < saut-de-ligne_UTF-8 > tmp
mv tmp saut-de-ligne_UTF-8
```

Comment: Yes but if I don't mistake the two files have to be different for a tr